# Lines appearing on vector layer after panning in QGIS

Tags: qgis

One of my vector layers is creating random-seeming lines whenever I pan across the map. It's only one layer and the lines disappear if I turn it off. It doesn't appear in the print composer so it isn't ultimately that big of a deal, but it makes me wonder if something else is going on. Pictures are below, taken after panning just a bit between each one. Final pic shows the fill color blurs along with the border.

[image: first pic]

[image: second pic]

[image: third pic]

[image: fourth pic]

Comment: Possibly related to this bug https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11441

Comment: Yeah that looks like it. My artifacts aren't nearly as pronounced but maybe the layer just isn't complex enough. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: I had similar artefacts that *did* show in the print composer, and were thus a bigger deal. Turning off multi-core rendering didn't help; what fixed it was clipping the layer to some bounds just outside the area that I wanted to show.

Answer (score 1):

Like SaultDon suggests, this is most likely related to a known error with multi core rendering: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11441

The bug report has been re-opened. No solution but at least it's not a complete mystery.

Comment: Deactivating either OTF or parallel rendering should fix the problem

Comment: I'll give that a try next time I'm working. Thanks!